# Can Microsoft Computer vision extract font information

Tags: fonts, computer-vision, ocr, tesseract, amazon-textract

I am extracting text using Microsoft computer vision, it is returning me a JSON response. Does Microsoft computer vision has an ability to extract font information along with the JSON response.
Or for that matter, does any OCR technology return font-information at the moment??

Comment: And what would you be thinking about when you say "font information"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically, OCR technologies try to get only text info. the algorithm of OCR focused only to detect text. As far as I am concerned there is no  feature to return which font it is. ( exp. pytesseract, MCV etc.)

To get information about font you can try to train a dataset like CNN. After succesfully trained dataset can say to you which font it is.

Comment: From my experiences with Google Cloud vison OCR and ABBYY I can confirm that these OCR solution do not return any font information.

Comment: Hi, @Harsh Multani if this or any answer has solved your question please consider accepting it by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.